# AVAudio detect note/pitch/etc. iPhone xcode objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, audio, avaudiorecorder

I'm making an app on the iphone and I need a way of detecting the tune of the sounds coming in through the microphone. (I.e. A#, G, C♭, etc.)
I assumed I'd use AVAudio but I really don't know and I can't find anything in the documentation..

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Musical notes are nothing more than specific frequencies of sound. You will need a way to analyze all of the frequencies in your input signal, and then find a way to isolate the individual notes.

Finding frequencies in an audio signal is done using the [Fast Fourier Transform (FFT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform). There is plenty of source code available online to compute the FFT from an audio signal. In particular, [oScope](http://oscopeapp.com/opensource-fft-for-the-iphone) offers an open-source solution for the iPhone.

**Edit:** *[Pitch detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitch_detection_algorithm)* seems to be the technical name for what you are trying to do. The answers to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457228/pitch-recognition-of-musical-notes-on-a-smart-phone) here on SO may be of use.

Comment: Pitch is not the same as frequency.  A note can have a missing fundamental.

Comment: @hotpaw2: Interesting. Shows how much I know about music `;)`. In case anyone else is unclear on the difference, the following article spells it out quite nicely: http://emusician.com/tutorials/emusic_pitch_vs_frequency/

Comment: @e.James The article at emusician moved to: http://www.emusician.com/gear/1332/pitch-vs-frequency/36924

Comment: link changed from @e.james  http://www.emusician.com/gear/1332/pitch-vs-frequency/36924

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing built-in to the iOS APIs for musical pitch estimation.  You will have to code your own DSP function.  The FFTs in the Accelerate framework will give you spectral frequency information from a PCM sampled waveform, but frequency is different from psycho-perceptual pitch.

There are a bunch of good and bad ways to estimate frequency and pitch.  I have a long partial list of various estimation methods on my [DSP resources web page](http://www.nicholson.com/rhn/dsp.html).

You can look at Apple's aurioTouch sample app for an example of getting iOS device audio input and displaying it's frequency spectrum.

Comment: Hey, do you have a weblink for the audioTouch app?

Comment: Look under Development Resources : Sample Code on developer.apple.com

Comment: It's actually called [aurioTouch](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/aurioTouch/Introduction/Intro.html)

Answer (score 1):

Like @e.James said, you are looking to find the pitch of a note, its called Pitch Detection. There are a ton of resources at CCRMA, Stanford University for what you are looking for. Just [google](http://www.google.com/search?gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=pitch%20detection%20site:ccrma.stanford.edu) for Pitch Detection and you will see a brilliant collection of algorithms. As far as wanting to find the FFT of blocks of Audio Samples, you could use the built-in FFT function of the Accelerate Framework (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398753/using-the-apple-fft-and-accelerate-framework) and [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Conceptual/vDSP_Programming_Guide/UsingFourierTransforms/UsingFourierTransforms.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005147-CH202-SW1)) or use the [MoMu toolkit](http://momu.stanford.edu/). Using MoMu has the benefit of it's functions decomposing the audio stream into samples for you and easy application of the FFT using it's own functions.